# How to wait for button to generate then execute next line of code

Tags: javascript

I currently have a generate button that executes when clicked. It then goes through a data base and takes a significant amount of time to load the results into a table. My line of code is used to sort the table. My problem is that I believe that the sorting is being run before the table is generated hence the table is not being sorted. I realized that when I place a break point at the sorting line and wait for the table to load, then the sorting occurs. It is just when I do not have a break point that the table is not being sorted. In turn I decided to use windows.onload function. But that did not help, I still received the same functionality as before.

```
document.getElementById("button").click();

        if(arrow == "up")
        {   
            window.onload = function()
            {
                sort("col_one");
            }
         }
```

As you can see the button is being programmatically pressed then the sort is to happen. I am not sure how to go about fixing this. I am avoiding the use of jquery.

Comment: Your use of `window.onload` is redundant -- if you're trying to trigger the function inside that seemingly undefined if statement, just call it. using `window.onload` runs that function when the `window` loads.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when loading a local file once.

I don't really understand what is the table you're talking about, but if it's from `<input type="file" id="fileInput">`,  i believe this will work =)
    var data;
    function readFile(evt) {
                    var f = evt.target.files[0];

```
                if (f) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    // When the file has been correctly loaded
                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        // We store the result in global var
                        data = r.result;

                        /* HERE YOU CAN DO YOUR SORTING JOB             */
                        /* Your table is stored in data as a big string */
                    }

                    // We have to precise the type of data we want to have in the end.
                    r.readAsBinaryString(f);

                } else {
                    alert("Failed to load file");
                }
            }


document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Hope it helps !